ITFoxtec.Identity SAML - Invalid Signature
I am using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 (4.11.3) to implement SSO using SAML on a test app. My IdP is Azure AD and I've setup and configured an enterprise SAML app registration.
I'm able to login successfully but when invoking the return URL on this line binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
I'm getting this error: "Invalid Signature". I've checked the metadata and the signing algorithm is the same as configured (SHA256). I've checked the following links for assistance but no joy:
https://tkit.dev/2020/05/25/a-potential-fix-for-itfoxtech-identity-saml2-signature-is-invalid-error/
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/issues/10
Here is my config:
Nuget package references:


appsettings.json

azure app reg saml settings

SAML metadata for signing algorithm

Error Message

Am I missing something small?
Thanks and Cheers
